# Switch between a list of all elements and display of selected element

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to display a list to select an element. By selecting an element I want to show a edit form. Therefore I'm using reactiveVar, but I don't get the id of the selected element to the edit form / helper to get all needed data.

Maybe this is bad coding and there is a much better way to switch between a list and a display for the selected element!

*`Users` is just taken as an example. Could be any collection/data*

**templates**

```
<template name="users">

    {{#if userId}}
        {{ > userEdit userId}}
    {{else}}

        <h1>List</h1>

        <div id="usersList">
            <ul>
                {{#each users}}
                    <li data-id="{{_id}}">{{users.name}}</li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </div>

    {{/if}}

</template>

<template name="userEdit">

    <h1>Edit User</h1>

    <form id="userEdit" data-id="{{user._id}}">
        <label><input type="text" name="name" value="{{user.name}}"> Name</label>
    </form>

</template>
```

**helpers**

```
Template.users.helpers({
    users:      function() { return Users.find({}) },
    userId:     function() { return Template.instance().userId.get(); }
});

Template.userEdit.helpers({
    user:       function() { return Users.findOne({ _id: Template.instance().parentView.userId.get() }); }
});
```

**events**

```
Template.users.onCreated(function() {
    this.userId = new ReactiveVar();
});
Template.users.events({
    'click #usersList li': function(event, template) {
        var $this = $(event.currentTarget),
            id    = $this.attr('data-id');

        if (id)
            template.userId.set(id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't use ReactiveVar for cross template. Use Session instead. Try this and let me know:

```
Template.users.events({
  'click #usersList li': function(event, template) {
    Session.set('userId', this._id)
    console.log(Session.get('userId'));
  }
});

Template.userEdit.helpers({
  user: function() {
    return Users.findOne({ _id: Session.get('userId')});
  }
});
```

Comment: Of course you can use a ReactiveVar across templates, it just depends on how you scope it and/or how your template js is organized.

Comment: No you can't http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar. But you can with some trick (one you've said) which is not easy for new user

Comment: Hardly a trick, basic js. Nowhere in that doc is a Template even mentioned.

Comment: "ReactiveVars don't have global names, like the "foo" in Session.get("foo"). Instead, they may be created and used locally, for example attached to a template instance, as in: this.foo.get()"

Comment: `myGlobalReactiveVar = new ReactiveVar(0)` creates a global reactive var.

Comment: Haven't tested but make sense. I feel better to use Session though as it persist hot code push